# QML canvas zoom and scroll/pan

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, qml

I'm trying to make a canvas in QML in which you can scroll/pan and zoom. I'm having troubles with the sizing of the canvas. When I zoom out, The size of the canvas becomes smaller and I get an area of no canvas on the right and the bottom. I have tried a lot and nothing seems to work. Here's a QML example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

    Rectangle {
        id: modellerDatapane

        property double factor : 1.5

        ScrollView {
            id: scrollCanvas
            anchors.fill: parent

            Flickable{
                id: flickableCanvas
                anchors.fill: parent
                contentWidth: canvas.width
                contentHeight: canvas.height

                Canvas {
                    Rectangle{
                        border.width: 20
                        color: "transparent"
                        border.color: "red"
                        anchors.fill:parent
                    }

                    property bool fill: true
                    property bool stroke: true
                    property real alpha: 1.0
                    property real scale : 5
                    property real rotate : 5
                    antialiasing: true

                    id: canvas
                    height: 5000
                    width: 5000

                    state : "visible"
                    transform : Scale{
                        id : tform
                    }

                    onPaint: {
                        console.log("painted")
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        var originX = 100
                        var originY = 100
                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                        ctx.translate(originX, originX);
                        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
                        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
                        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
                        ctx.lineWidth = 3;

                        ctx.translate(originX, originY)
                        ctx.scale(tform.xScale, tform.yScale);
                        ctx.rotate(1);
                        ctx.translate(-originX, -originY)

                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(75,40);
                        ctx.bezierCurveTo(75,37,70,25,50,25);
                        ctx.bezierCurveTo(20,25,20,62.5,20,62.5);
                        ctx.bezierCurveTo(20,80,40,102,75,120);
                        ctx.bezierCurveTo(110,102,130,80,130,62.5);
                        ctx.bezierCurveTo(130,62.5,130,25,100,25);
                        ctx.bezierCurveTo(85,25,75,37,75,40);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        if (canvas.fill)
                            ctx.fill();
                        if (canvas.stroke)
                            ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.restore();

                    }


                    MouseArea {
                        parent: scrollCanvas
                        anchors.fill: canvas
                        propagateComposedEvents: true

                        onWheel: {
                            if(wheel.angleDelta.y > 0){  // zoom in
                                canvasZoomIn();
                            }
                            else{                        // zoom out
                                canvasZoomOut();
                            }
                        }
                        onPressed:{
                            mouse.accepted = false
                        }
                        onPositionChanged:{mouse.accepted = false}
                        onReleased:{mouse.accepted = false}
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        function canvasZoomOut(){
            scaleCanvas(1/factor);

        }

        function canvasZoomIn(){
            scaleCanvas(factor);

        }

        function scaleCanvas(scaleFactor){
            tform.xScale *=scaleFactor;
            tform.yScale *=scaleFactor;
            canvas.height *= scaleFactor;
            canvas.width *= scaleFactor;
        }

    }
```

This is what the canvas looks like (the canvas is red, the white area is nothing):

[This is what it looks like when you scroll all the way to the right, without zooming. (You can't scroll out of the canvas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnrxW.png)

[This is what it looks like when you zoom out one step, and scroll to the right. (The scroll bar is too long and you can scroll out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDo2C.png)

Comment: A minimal example will get you answers quicker.

Comment: @Mitch I don't really know if I can make it any smaller. This is my first question by the way. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Perhaps minimal was not the best choice of words. :p It doesn't necessary have to be less code, just enough code that it actually runs. If that means adding slightly more code, it's fine.

Comment: @Mitch I changed the code so it's runnable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I added a border around the canvas to better show the problem.

Comment: If you don't want the canvas to become smaller, you shouldn't change its `width` and `height`. What happens if you comment out the last two lines in `scaleCanvas()`? It seems to work for me, according to your requirements.

Comment: @Mitch Try zooming out one step and scrolling to the right or the bottom. You'll see an area of white which is empty space.

Comment: Can you post an image of the expected result? I'm a bit unclear on what you're after. If you don't want any area outside of the `Canvas` to be visible, you need to limit the scale factor.

Comment: @Mitch I added 2 new images in my question. One is without zooming, which works as expected. And one zoomed one step out, in which you can scroll/pan out of the canvas. Hope this makes it clearer.